# condition for specific pages

Tags: php, page-template

I have a php page template used for all archive product categories. If I want to change the button on one of the categories, is there an 'if' 'then' condition I can put in?
e.g button for all categories says 'book now' and takes them to a calendly booking page. one category is not available for booking but I still want them to be able to enquire about it. I was hoping I could add a condition where the buttons for that category would say 'Enquire' link to the contact page

https://snipboard.io/5ycTSh.jpg

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do it would be:

```
if ( is_category ('4') ) {
 echo '<a class="btn" href="">Enquire</a>';
} else {
 echo '<a class="btn" href="">Calendly link</a>';
}
```

Obviously you would change "4" to whatever the specific category number is.

Also, the WordPress template hierarchy could be helpful if you have add'l changes:

https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#category

[image: Graphical view of the Template Hierarchy]

If you want a special template for the category 4, you just save the template file as category-4.php in your child theme folder.